# how to get a struct that inside of a struct and assign it to an array of structs

Tags: c, arrays, linked-list, struct

I am sorry if this is a really simple question but I am really rusty in C and googling hasn't helped so far. I have a C function that takes in an array of structs and an integer:

```
int foo(struct record *records, int n)
{

}
```

and also a linked list where each node has a struct:

```
struct rnode
{
    struct record rec;
    struct rnode *next;
}
```

and struct record is:

```
struct record
{
    enum recordtype type;
    union recordvalue
    {
        int intval;
        char strval[19];
    } value;
};
```

inside foo(struct record *, int*) I am iterating through the linked list and assigning the first "n" struct records into the array like:

```
int foo(struct record *records, int n)
{
    int count = 0;
    struct rnode *cur = recordlist;
    while(cur != NULL)
    {
        records[count] = cur->rec; //Basically, how do I write this line?
        printf("%d\n", records[count].type); //Both these print the correct values
        printf("%d\n", records[count].value.intval); //Prints correct values
        count++;
    }
}
```

I tried doing:
    records[count] = cur->rec

which compiles but when I do the following:

```
struct record *records = malloc(sizeof(struct record)*n);
foo(records, n); //This should populate the array records but it isn't.
//If I print record[0].value.intval here I get 0.
```

but when I pass &records[0] to another function like:

```
checkrecord(&record[0]);
```

where checkrecord is declared:

```
checkrecord(const struct record *r)
```

inside that function, r->type and r->value.intval both return 0 instead of the correct value.

I'm pretty sure I'm storing the struct record into the array correctly, but I'm not sure what else I'm doing wrong.

I don't mean to sound stubborn but the issue is that the checkrecord() function I am not at liberty to change but I can change how I pass the parameters to it.

Comment: `records[count] = cur->rec` is right, but I don't get what you want to accomplish by checking `&record[1]` . You'd want something inside the struct, records[1].some_member

Comment: @nos is spot on... `&record[1]` is simply asking for a pointer to the first record... it can never be "the *value* of the struct"

Comment: Yea I misstyped some stuff. I edited it now to clarify a little bit.

Comment: Then something entierly different is going on, there's nothing wrong in the code posted. Try make up a complete example that gives this behavior. You left out the important parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help everyone. It was actually a memory issue elsewhere. The above code is correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
*(cur->rec)
```

This should not work given the sample you posted.

The correct way to copy the record struct is:

```
records[count] = cur->rec;
```

If you want a pointer to the actual struct in the linked list, you need to have an array of pointers to record, instead of your current array of records. In that case, you assign with:

```
records[count] = &(cur->rec);
```

Answer (score 0):

records[count] = cur->rec is correct, but you're missing cur = cur->next. And record[1] is the second record, and &record[1] is its address.

Comment: yea I left out the cur = cur->next because that part wasnt really important. is there a way to be given an address to a struct in an array of structs and still get the values inside that struct?

Comment: If you have an address of a struct, it doesn't matter whether it's in an array or not. Given struct foo* p = &somefoo, p->bar gets the value bar from inside somefoo. If that's not what you're asking for, then you need to be more precise.

Comment: @Yiling Ok, looking at your edit, with "checkrecord(&record[0]); ...
checkrecord(const struct record *r)
... r->value" that's all correct, so the problem isn't with the way you're accessing them but something else. Try posting a more complete example.